# Can't get multiple span class text with selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm getting error when I try to scrape a flashscore match summary. Example:
[flashscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pCTu.png)

I want to get the for example all the results in those page but doing **driver.find_element_by_class("h2h__result")** it only takes the first result. (putted inside a for obv)
If i try to do **driver.find_elements_by_class** i get error and i can't understand why.
Code example:

```
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/Qs85KCdA/#h2h/overall")
time.sleep(2)

h2h = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rows")


for x in h2h:
    p = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.h2h__regularTimeResult")
    print(p.text)
```

Can someone help me to understand where i'm doing wrong? Thank you a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

The elements with class-name `rows` is highlighting the whole table. Use the class-name `h2h__row` so that all the rows are focused and will be able to extract the details from that particular row.

Try below `xpaths` to get the elements.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/Qs85KCdA/#h2h/overall")

rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='h2h__row']")

for row in rows:
    results = row.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']") # Use a dot in the xpath to find elements with in an element
    print(results.text)
```

You can also use below `CSS_SELECTOR` to get the elements directly.

```
regularTimeResult = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.h2h__row span.h2h__regularTimeResult")

for item in regularTimeResult:
    print(item.text)
```

**Update:**

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='h2h__row']")

for row in rows:
    results = row.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']") # Use a dot in the xpath to find elements with in an element
    if "0 : 0" not in results.text:
        print(results.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the perfect solution. And if I would delete the 0:0 score from the span text how to do it? I've tried with everything even translate() or replace() but nothing worked.

Comment: @MartinCvetanoski - Have updated the answer. Can just add a `if loop` to filter out `0 - 0`.  And if the answer was helpful, accept the same. Click on the right mark option available for the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much mate. I will do of course is the minimum for you. Last thing when I try to do print(len(results.text)) it gives me only 5 elements and not 11 like it should do. Should i put a append() in the for loop or what is going wrong? I'm sorry I know i bothered you with those questions. Sorry again.

Comment: Length of `results.text` means length of `0 : 0` which is 5. I think you should do length of `rows` outside the for loop.